# NO_DATA_FOUND exception handling with Select Into MULTIPLE variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have looked for a while now for a solution to this issue, and all the NO_DATA_FOUND handling tutorials I found only show how to do it when doing a Select Into with only one column into one variable.

First, here is my code:

```sql
BEGIN 
    OPEN c_no_source; 
    LOOP 
        DECLARE 
            l_price_code  VARCHAR2(20) := ''; 
            l_price_level VARCHAR(10) := ''; 
            l_code_date   DATE := p_effective_date; 
        BEGIN 
            FETCH c_no_source INTO c_no_source_row;
                exit WHEN c_no_source%NOTFOUND;
            BEGIN 
                WITH codeList AS /* liste des dates ayant une donnée avant la date effective incluse. */
                (
                    SELECT distinct
                        NVL(effective_date,p_effective_date) as effective_date,
                        NVL(user_group2,'') as price_code, 
                        NVL(user_group3,'') as price_level
                    FROM  DGA_Service.Hjvsecmaster_Hist
                    WHERE   effective_date <= p_effective_date
                        AND user_group2 IS NOT NULL
                        AND security_alias = c_no_source_row.security_alias
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC
                )
                SELECT price_code, price_level, effective_date 
                INTO   l_price_code, l_price_level, l_code_date 
                FROM   codelist 
                WHERE  ROWNUM = 1; 
                EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN NULL;

                ...
                [UPDATE statement using the variables] 
                ...
            END; 
        END; 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c_no_source; 
END;
```

What I'm trying to do is take the top 1 result of my `codeList` temp result set into three separate variables.
However one of the three columns in `codeList` will often be `NULL`. And none of my 3 variables will be set.
I tried to handle the exception but I can't get my code to insert the columns that DO have a value into their respective variables. If even one of the columns is NULL then none of them are inserted into their variable.

I would like the Select Into statement to set the variables that it CAN set.

I tried to handle them all separately using something like this:

```sql
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    BEGIN
        IF price_code IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_code := price_code; END IF;
        IF price_level IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_level := price_level; END IF;
        IF effective_date IS NOT NULL THEN l_code_date := effective_date; END IF;
    END;
```

But I got the following error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 294, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PRICE_CODE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 294, column 15:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 295, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PRICE_LEVEL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 295, column 15:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 296, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EFFECTIVE_DATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 296, column 15:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

So I ran out of ideas. I tried specifying the temp table name, to no avail, like this:

```sql
IF codeList.price_code IS NOT NULL
```

I would love any help on this issue. The package this piece of code runs in is already heavy and I would prefer not to have to get each column with a separate `With ... As () Select Into` clause.

Comment: @Ben in the first original code block I execute `NULL` if the exception is thrown. The most common case occuring is that the `codeList` table has between 5 and 10 rows, but each row will have one of the 3 columns `NULL`.

I assumed it was the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error because when I just used `EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN NULL;` none of my 3 variables where set even though 2 of them should have been. I might be mistaken, in which case I don't know why my variables aren't set with the columns that DO have a value.

Comment: All I want is to find a way to grab each row in the loop and set whatever variable I have a value for, then set the others with ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I get you; most of your problem is caused by you nesting PL/SQL blocks incorrectly.

Your update statement is contained within the EXCEPTION block, which means it'll only get executed if the exception is thrown. Secondly, you're referencing the *columns* directly in the following:

```
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    BEGIN
        IF price_code IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_code := price_code; END IF;
        IF price_level IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_level := price_level; END IF;
        IF effective_date IS NOT NULL THEN l_code_date := effective_date; END IF;
    END;
```

This is the cause of your compilation error.

Lastly, if there is a single row in your `select into` then *every* variable will be set, so there's no need to try to deal with this.

```
BEGIN 
    OPEN c_no_source; 
    LOOP 
        DECLARE 
            l_price_code  VARCHAR2(20); 
            l_price_level VARCHAR(10); 
            l_code_date   DATE := p_effective_date; 
        BEGIN 
            FETCH c_no_source INTO c_no_source_row;
                exit WHEN c_no_source%NOTFOUND;
            BEGIN 
                WITH codelist AS (
                 SELECT DISTINCT effective_date
                      , user_group2 AS price_code
                      , user_group3 AS price_level 
                   FROM hjvsecmaster_hist 
                   WHERE effective_date <= p_effective_date 
                     AND user_group2 IS NOT NULL 
                     AND security_alias = c_no_source_row.security_alias 
                   ORDER BY 1 DESC
                ) 
                SELECT price_code, price_level, effective_date 
                INTO   l_price_code, l_price_level, l_code_date 
                FROM   codelist 
                WHERE  ROWNUM = 1; 
                EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
                   -- All variables are their initial setting
                   null;
            END; 
           ...
              [UPDATE statement using the variables] 
           ...
        END; 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c_no_source; 
END;
```

This is normally a highly inefficient way of doing this. If you can fit everything into a single UPDATE or [MERGE](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html) then I would do so. You don't appear to have any additional logic so it should be possible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm a dumbass for forgetting to take the UPDATE statement out of the exception block. And yeah I just set the EXCEPTION handling to do `NULL` and everything's good.

Comment: How would you integrate all this into an update statement? I'm looking into a solution using MERGE.

Comment: @EplusL, I'm not sure :-). I don't have your original cursor select or your update statement. If you post a new question with all 3 I'm sure someone might be able to help!

Comment: I found a solution but it was convoluted because I had to add an extra column to my select inside the with and do some weird joins. Plus as the with clause is very fast, my code in this version is still unaffected performance wise compared to before I had to add this entire cursor bit. It takes maybe 4 seconds instead of 3.5 to generate 8000 lines, and this is a daily process, where the customer is used to exec times around 1 minute for other processes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> However one of the three will often be NULL, and trigger the
>   NO_DATA_FOUND error, and none of my 3 variables will be set

NO_DATA_FOUND is raised when the query does not return any **rows**.  It has nothing to do with the column values. They could all be null and the statement would succeed.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    BEGIN
        IF price_code IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_code := price_code; END IF;
        IF price_level IS NOT NULL THEN l_price_level := price_level; END IF;
        IF effective_date IS NOT NULL THEN l_code_date := effective_date; END IF;
    END;
```

your variables are prefixed with "l_" and you are using the column names eg.price_code  in your comparision, hence the error. **More importantly, NO_DATA_FOUND would mean all the variable values are null, so this exception block does not do anything.**

All you'd probably need is this.

if you don't want to insert null values for a given id (if all are null)

```
BEGIN
   insert into target_table (id, col1, col2, col3)
   select id, col1, col2, col3
     from (target_table)
     where not (col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null);
   commit;
end;
/
```

If there is no data for a given id, nothing is inserted. If atleast one of them is not null, then these values are inserted.